# Ordering columns of a data frame

Tags: r, sorting

I am interested to order columns of the data frame give below

```
structure(list(DETECTION = c(0.000219, 0.000673, 0.000322, 0.602006, 
0.000468, 0.204022, 0.000491, 0.003067), VALUE = structure(1:8, .Label = c("10071_s_at", 
"1053_at", "117_at", "1255_g_at", "1294_at", "1320_at", "1405_i_at", 
"14312_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DETECTION", "VALUE"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want numeric column (`DETECTION`) at the second.

I tried something here

```
d1 <- data[1, , drop = FALSE]
nums <- d1[, nn <- sapply(d1, is.numeric)]

ch <- d1[, !nn, drop = FALSE]
id <- names(ch[, grepl('_at$', as.character(unlist(ch))), drop = FALSE])
p <- names(nums)
d <- data[,c(id,p)]
```

However `names(nums)` returns `NULL` . What is going wrong here.

Comment: @LegalizeIt The data frame may not always be in the same order. It may in order also, so ur code will disorder it

Comment: you want to do it by names? `d1[, c("DETECTION", "VALUE")]
`

Comment: How do you want to order?  If you are ordering my names, `data[order(names(data))]`, DETECTIon is the first column

Comment: I want numeric column at the second, but if the numeric column is already at second, it should not disorder it. consider it an automatic process without knowing the data

Comment: Suppose if there are 10 columns and you have numeric and other class columns, how do you want to order it

Comment: This stands for only two columns, if more columns something else will go on

Comment: If there are only two columns, wouldn't it be easier as what Legalizelt suggested

Comment: off-course not , as i already mentioned the data is not known, there is no guarantee of the same column names. Column names can be anything

Comment: Try `data[sapply(data, is.numeric)+1]`

Comment: @akrun That sounds good. Can U please also tell why `names(nums)` above returns `NULL`

Comment: @Hashim I haven't tested that with many cases.  Also, what if both the columns are numeric.

Comment: That is not going to be the case i think. This will get executed when data is of said pattern

Comment: OP `names(nums)` is `NULL` because the dimension was dropped when you defined it. Try: `nums <- d1[, nn <- sapply(d1, is.numeric), drop=F]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names(nums)` is `NULL` because the dimensions were dropped. You can add the argument `drop` to keep the dimensions as they are:

```
names(nums)
#NULL

nums <- d1[, nn <- sapply(d1, is.numeric), drop=FALSE]

names(nums)
#[1] "DETECTION"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt <- as.data.table(data)
```

From R help : " When it's required to reorder the columns of a data.table, the idiomatic way is to use setcolorder(x, neworder), instead of doing x <- x[, neworder, with=FALSE]. This is because the latter makes an entire copy of the data.table, which maybe unnecessary in most situations."

```
setcolorder(dt,c("VALUE","DETECTION"))
```

Comment: you may also wish to use `setDT(data);setcolorder(data,ord_column_vector)` to avoid reassigning the table at all.